# How to use svgr with webpack and TypeScript in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have `svg` files stored in separate files. I want to load them in React and use as react components as below:

```
import SampleIcon from '@/components/editor/icons/add-column-after.svg';
<SampleIcon className="my-icon" />
```

I installed `svgr` and used in `next.config.js` as below:

```
  webpack: (config) => {
    // SVG
    // Grab the existing rule that handles SVG imports
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) =>
      rule.test?.test?.('.svg')
    );

    config.module.rules.push(
      // Reapply the existing rule, but only for svg imports ending in ?url
      {
        ...fileLoaderRule,
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
      },
      // Convert all other *.svg imports to React components
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: fileLoaderRule.issuer,
        resourceQuery: { not: [...fileLoaderRule.resourceQuery.not, /url/] }, // exclude if *.svg?url
        use: [
          {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
            options: {
              typescript: true,
              ext: 'tsx',
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    );

    // Modify the file loader rule to ignore *.svg, since we have it handled now.
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;

    return config;
  },
```

It works but intellisense does not work i.e. `SampleIcon` has `any` type. I tried to create `declarations.d.ts` file in root directory and add it in `tsconfig.json` in `include` list but does not work as well. Here is my declaration:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React from 'react';
  const SVG: React.VFC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  export default SVG;
}
```

Any ideas?